# F# Silverlight RPC: pre-fill paginated data

Tags: f#

Thanks to everybody who has helped over the past few months trying to help me get my silverlight / f# prototype up and running (started in the RC version of VS - Ugh).  The last problem we are trying to solve is an RPC issue.

We need to have the ability to paginate RPC calls, such that the first page is requested and bound to the grid and displayed, while the otehr pages are prefilled in the background and concatenated together.  I guess psuedo code would look like this:

```
let pageNo = 1
let page1Data  = JsonRpc.getSomeData(pageNo)

let grid.datasource <- page1Data
let grid.suspendFiltering <- true

// run the remainder in background
let allData : list ref = page1Data ref
for pageNo in [2..totalPages]
    allData := allData @ JsonRpc.getSomeData(pageNo)

let grid.datasource <- allData
let grid.suspendFiltering <- true
```

I appologize for the code above, I tried to make it as F# like as possible (writing in this text window); another flaw is the need to use call backs to bind the data to grids etc.

The question approaches might be used to solve this problem and what is the most approriate?

Comment: Hmmmmm... I've read this question over and over and can't figure out where the problem is. If you want to get your entire dataset, expose a `JsonRpc.getAllData` method to do exactly that. And your comment *"another flaw is the need to use call backs to bind the data to grids"* has no context, because as near as I can tell, your `JsonRpc.getSomeData` method looks like a synchronous method, there's no reference to callbacks anywhere. The only thing out of the ordinary the use of `@` in a loop instead of a more idiomatic `[yield! page1Data; for pageNo in totalPages do yield! getSomeData(pageNo)]`

Comment: I see (not as clear as I need to be)  - lets say each paginated request takes 2 seconds to fill.  If I have 10 pages thats too long for a user to wait to get all the data.  SO I want to show the first page and fill the rest of the dataset in in the background.  I did omit the callbacks for sake of simplicity in this example.  Even in a simpler model, I still need to show one page of data, get all the data, and then rebind the grid to the entire set...

Does this clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... something like this? (typing in browser so may contain errors):

```
module Loader

open System
open System.Threading

let totalPages = 20

// emulation of long-running data loading routine
let private loadPageData (page : int) = 
    async {
        do! Async.Sleep(1000)
        return List.replicate 5 page
    }

// loader - notifies UI about new data via callback
let loadAsync (callback : System.Action<_>) = 
    let syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
    let doLoad = async {

        // load first page and immediately feed it to callback
        let! page1Data = loadPageData 1

        do! Async.SwitchToContext syncContext
        callback.Invoke(ResizeArray<_>(page1Data))

        // load remaining data in the background 
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
        let allData = ResizeArray<_>(page1Data)            

        for page in 2..totalPages do
            let! pageData = loadPageData page
            allData.AddRange(pageData)

        do! Async.SwitchToContext syncContext
        callback.Invoke(allData)
        }

    Async.Start doLoad
```

On UI side it will appear like this (i.e. data - ListBox or some other control)

```
Loader.loadDataAsync(list => data.ItemSource = list)
```

Comment: Thank you - this actually looks like one of the designs I was thinking about implementing.  We simply call "the call back" twice loading after P1 and then afetr Pn.  I am not familiar with the details of the Async module - but it reads straight forward and I can look it up in depth.  Thank you.  Does anybody else have thoughts on this design?